# Find $B$ if $AB=BC$ and $A,C$ are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ and $C$ are known invertible complex matrices of possibly different orders. If $B$ is an unknown matrix of appropriate order such that $AB = BC$, then how could one solve for $B$?

Comment: There isn't always just one solution. $B=0$ is always a solution, and if $A=C$ for example then $B=I$ is also a solution.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Agreed. Notice that this a homogeneous linear system on the unknown coefficients of $B$ so the solutions form a vector space. The case $A=C$ usually implies a higher dimensional solution space. For in that case $B$ can be any polynomial on $A$ (those commute with $A=C$).

Comment: A brute force method: Write down the matrix of the mapping $T:B\mapsto ABC^{-1}$ and find the eigenspace belonging to eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ of $T$ :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve the problem theoretically and then compute it for low dimensions.

Consider $\phi: M(n, \mathbb{K}) \to M(n, \mathbb{K})$ mapping $X \mapsto AXC^{-1}-X$ and find the kernel.

Comment: Should you have $\phi(X)=AXC^{-1}-X$?

Comment: Oh, ye, scuse me.

Comment: then please correct or delete your answer...