# Solving the solution space of D1A = AD2 for the matix A

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Is there a better way to come up with a defined vector space for A in D1A = AD2 where D1 and D2 are diagonal matrices? The closest thing I was able to find is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939171/find-b-if-ab-bc-and-a-c-are-invertible) where D1 and D2 were instead complex and invertible. The given answer is to:

Use the matrix of the mapping T:A↦D1AD2−1 and find the eigenspace belonging to eigenvalue λ=1 of T

I know my diagonal doesn't contain 0s making D1 and D2 invertible. Does the fact that D1 and D2 are diagonal provide a better way to solve the vector space solution?

Comment: Your first line asks for a better way, a better way than what?

Comment: @MichaelBurr The method of using the mapping and finding the eigenspace. I put my current solution in the second line. It didn't feel right to start without explaining the problem.

Comment: Hint: The equation corresponding to the $(i,j)$th entry is $(D_1)_{ii} A_{ij} = A_{ij} (D_2)_{jj}$.